# SQL - return records on the fist date where records exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table with records that are only populated on weekdays. I have an external function that returns a DateTime (and could possibly fall on a weekend).

If the date falls on the weekend there will be not records so I'd like to return the record set for the following Monday. What is the easiest way to do this?

For Example:

```
SELECT 1 As Id, CAST('19 July 2013' AS datetime) Date INTO #DATEDATA UNION ALL --friday
SELECT 2 As Id, CAST('22 July 2013' AS datetime) --monday

DECLARE @WeekendDate DateTime = CAST('20 July 2013' AS datetime)
```

The select Statement would need to return record 2.

Is the easiest way to do this some kind of while loop where I count the records and increment the date by 1 day or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Min(Date) 
from #DATEDATA
Where Date>=@WeekendDate
```

or

```
Select * from #DATEDATA
where Date=
(
Select Min(Date) 
from #DATEDATA
Where Date>=@WeekendDate
)
```

Comment: so obvious now that I see it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you could also make a function to return the required date

```
create function dbo.mydate( @d datetime)
returns datetime
as 
begin 
  declare @day int
  set @day = datepart(dw,@d)
  return case @day 
           when 1 then dateadd(dd,1,@d) 
           when 7 then dateadd(dd,2,@d)
           else @d end
end
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412dc/1